# Migrate Image Cache presets to Image Style Drupal 7 Upgrade

Tags: 7, updating, media

I have recently upgraded my site to drupal 7 which uses Image Cache module. I migrated all the presets to Image Styles using the script mentioned in the below link.
http://drupal.org/node/1316472

When I visited nodes in my site, it shows me big images irrespective of the style that's applied  to it. In some nodes, the images are missing.
I have few cck image field associated with few node types.

So whats the correct step I should take to upgrade my drupal site such that all the images are displayed with the correct image style effects applied to it.

I searched for documentation on drupal image & image cache modules upgrade, but didnt find any. Please guide me through the process.